# Google Sheets - Script to move cells from two columns to the bottom of the next two columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

[Image of my Spreadsheet Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdqqh.png)
I am making a Sheets version of a KanBan board. Basically, all items start on the very first column, and as I complete a single task for each item, I select a dropdown on the cell next to it, and it moves over to the bottom of the next column.

My issue is that I can't figure out how the script to get the cells moved over without erasing the data in the existing cells.

I've attached a screenshot of the page that I've made for this. This is one of my latest attempts, and I've got nothing to work now. I'm going backwards in progress.

```
function GetDataToNextColumn() {
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var lastRow = source.getLastRow();
  var mainBoard = source.getSheetByName("MainBoard")
  var target_sheet = mainBoard.getDataRange();
  var source_sheet = mainBoard.getRange("A2:B");
  var i = 1;
  
  while (i <= lastRow) {
  if (mainBoard.getRange("B"+i).getValue() == "Scheduled") {
    
    var data = mainBoard.getRange('A' + i + ':B' + i).getValues()[0];

    mainBoard.appendRow(data);
  }
  
   else {
      i++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: About `I've attached a screenshot of the page that I've made for this.`, where can I see it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Apologies, it apparently didn't take the first time. It's on there now, at the top of the post. @Tanaike

Answer (score 0):

**Move first to columns to bottom of next two columns**

```
function getDataToNextColumn() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let cols1_2 = vs.map(r => [r[0], r[1]]);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, 3, cols1_2.length, cols1_2[0].length).setValues(cols1_2);
  sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).clearContent();
}

function getDataToColumn(col) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0")
  let vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow(), sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let cols1_2 = vs.map(r => [r[0], r[1]]);
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow() + 1, col, cols1_2.length, cols1_2[0].length).setValues(cols1_2);//edited this
  sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 2).clearContent();
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: I like this, but is there a to specify which exact column I want them to move to? I've now attached a screenshot of the setup I have. I'm hoping to make it more of a "move cell to named range column that the cell's adjacent dropdown selects"